# s3fs mount non empty folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I have mounted the s3 bucket to `/images` on EC2 everything was fine and working.
Now I noticed that `/images` got unmounted, what I mean is uploaded files are no longer appearing on the s3 bucket, instead `/images` is using EC2 memory.

I tried to re-mount it but s3fs complaining that `/images` is not empty and suggesting me to use the `nonempty` option.

My questions are:

1. If I re-mount using `nonempty` option will it keep files inside the `/images`?
2. How can I synchronize `/images` with the s3 bucket? (upload files that are not on s3)

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you remount s3fs to `/images`, the existing data will be kept but you cannot access it until you umount s3fs
2. I would `mv images images-tmp`, remount s3fs, then `mv images-tmp/* images/`

It would be good to figure out why s3fs exited to prevent this from happening again.  Upgrading to the latest version may resolve this.  Otherwise please open a GitHub issue.